# Filtering complex list elements using JavaStreams - Code Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, java-stream

I have Complex List of elements. Each inner list contains 3 fields: Code, Name, Version.
I need to get final list of List which has max version numbers for each code.

Below code snippet working as expected but looking for effective solution.

```
List<List<Object>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Object>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

// each list contains => code,   name,   version
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code1", "Name1", 1));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code1", "Name1", 2));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code1", "Name1", 3));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code1", "Name1", 3));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code2", "Name2", 1));
lists.add(Arrays.asList("code2", "Name2", 2));

// get all uniqueCodes
List<Object> uniqueCodes = lists.stream().map(row -> row.get(0)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

// iterate over uniqueCodes 
uniqueCodes.stream().forEach(code -> {
    // get lists for this uniqueCode
    Supplier<Stream<List<Object>>> sameCodeLists = () -> lists.stream().filter(row -> row.get(0) == code);

    // get max version of this uniqueCode
    int maxVersion = sameCodeLists.get().mapToInt(row -> (int) row.get(2)).max().getAsInt();

    // for this uniqueCode, get all Lists containing Max Version
    finalList.addAll(sameCodeLists.get().filter(row -> (int) row.get(2) == maxVersion && row.get(0) == code).collect(Collectors.toList()));
});
System.out.println(finalList);
```

> ```
> Input: [[code1, Name1, 1], [code1, Name1, 2], [code1, Name1, 3], [code1, Name1, 3], [code2, Name2, 1], [code2, Name2, 2]]
>
> Output: [[code1, Name1, 3], [code1, Name1, 3], [code2, Name2, 2]]
> ```

This is appropriate and as expected. Looking for code optimization to finish the job with fewer iterations.

Comment: a better design would be to create a class to contain code,   name,   version then you can just have `List<T>` instead of `List<List<Object>>`. it will make your code _cleaner, more readable and maintainable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could greatly simplify it by

- creating a class and using its instances instead of `List<Object>`s;
- employing `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.maxBy`.

---

```
@Getter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class Entity {

  private final String code;
  private final String name;
  private final int version;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(
      new Entity("code1", "Name1", 1),
      new Entity("code1", "Name1", 2),
      new Entity("code1", "Name1", 3),
      new Entity("code1", "Name1", 3),
      new Entity("code2", "Name2", 1),
      new Entity("code2", "Name2", 2)
    );

    final Map<String, Optional<Entity>> result = entities.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getCode,
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Entity::getVersion))));

    System.out.println(result);
    // {
    //  code2=Optional[Entity(code=code2, name=Name2, version=2)], 
    //  code1=Optional[Entity(code=code1, name=Name1, version=3)]
    // }
  }

}
```

As @Aomine suggested in the comments, `Collectors.collectingAndThen` with a finisher function might be used to map it to the final result.

```
Map<String, Optional<Integer>> result = entities.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(Entity::getCode,
    collectingAndThen(maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Entity::getVersion)),
      opEntity -> opEntity.map(Entity::getVersion))));

System.out.println(result);
// {code2=Optional[2], code1=Optional[3]}
```

### UPDATE

It's not a trivial task, so Stream API may not be a good fit. Nevertheless, I came up with the following approach which seems to do the job.

```
List<Entity> result = entities.stream()
    // group by code and sort the resulting lists by version
    .collect(groupingBy(Entity::getCode, HashMap::new,
            collectingAndThen(toList(), e -> e.stream().sorted(comparingInt(Entity::getVersion).reversed()).collect(toList()))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    // keep only the max values
    .map(l -> l.size() > 0 ? l.stream().filter(i -> i.getVersion() == l.get(0).getVersion()).collect(toList()) : l)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(toList());

System.out.println(result);
// [
//  Entity(code=code2, name=Name2, version=2), 
//  Entity(code=code1, name=Name1, version=3), 
//  Entity(code=code1, name=Name1, version=3)
// ]
```

Comment: I was doing something similar on my IDE but came to the conclusion of using `toMap` instead and I'd suggest that approach to avoid having `Optional<Entity>` as the map values i.e. `entities.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Entity::getCode,
                        Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Entity::getVersion))));`

Comment: or you can stay with your current approach but use `collectingAndThen` with a finisher function to get a `Map<String, Entity>`. Also, another note, favour `comparingInt` over `comparing`.

Comment: @Aomine thank you. Yes, I was thinking about a finisher, that's what I would go with.

Comment: @Aomine certainly, it should've been `comparingInt`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko/@Aomine - If you observe output in the question, all list elements having max version needs to collected. In your answer, entitiy entry: ["code1", "Name1", 3] is two times. As duplicate entries allowed, So output should also contains two entries. Final output should be a list, Can we try without Map?

Comment: @Forece85 You need to update the question, then. Your 3rd sentence contradicts the output you are expecting. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thankyou @AndrewTobilko. If its not with streams what else approach can fasten/optimize the code

Comment: @Forece85 there is little to optimise assuming you are working on small sets of data. It wouldn't make a difference. The idea for a different approach would remain the same and I guess it would be even more verbose if it was implemented with plain Java.